# SPOOLing gives extra rows, copy-paste does not

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-developer

I am using oracle sql developer. My table has 58484 rows, but exporting to a csv gives 58532 rows! First I used this command (and tried fiddling with the set options for a bit to see what happened):

```
set trimspool on
set heading off
set pagesize 0
set wrap off
set feedback off
set newpage 0
SPOOL "C:\USERS\JULIANCIENFUEGOS\DESKTOP\TBLFACILITY_SURVEY.CSV"
SELECT /*csv*/ * FROM TBLFACILITY_SURVEY;
ORDER BY FACILITYID
SPOOL OFF;
```

When I do a regular expression search in the csv for "\n\n" or "\n,,,," nothing comes up, so there are neither blank lines, nor any rows that are empty comma separated lists.

If I copy and paste the table into excel, I get the proper number of rows.

Could someone explain this?

Comment: we don't support pagesize 0 in SQL Developer - try something 2 or higher. for that many rows i think you could set it to 60,000, so you'd have just the one header

Comment: Ok, I tried 2 and 60000 and still got extra rows. I tried using smaller tables of 5 rows and 10 rows, and don't get extra rows (besides the first couple of header lines). I think I'll just ignore this and stick with the copy paste method. Understanding comes with time! Your blog has been super helpful while learning about oracle, thanks!

Comment: setting it to two would print a header line every 2 rows - that's LOTS of extra lines. set it to a REALLY big number